# Input 'y' of 'Mul' Op has type float32 that does not match type int32 of argument 'x'

Tags: python-3.x

When I use this code on Linux. It works. But on windows it doesn't. By the way my python version is 3.5 on my windows

```
with graph.as_default():

 train_inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[batch_size])
 train_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[batch_size, 1])
 valid_dataset = tf.constant(valid_examples, dtype=tf.int32)


with tf.device('/cpu:0'):

 embeddings = tf.Variable(
    tf.random_uniform([vocabulary_size, embedding_size], -1.0, 1.0))
 embed = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, train_inputs)


 nce_weights = tf.Variable(
    tf.truncated_normal([vocabulary_size, embedding_size],
                        stddev=1.0 / math.sqrt(embedding_size)))
 nce_biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([vocabulary_size]))


loss = tf.reduce_mean(
  tf.nn.nce_loss(nce_weights, nce_biases, embed, train_labels,num_sampled, vocabulary_size))
```

Comment: I check the type of embed(float32) and train_labels(int32). Should I change the type one of them? and How?

Answer (score 12):

You need to convert train_labels type to `float32`. [You already mentioned that train_labels is of type `int32` and embed is of type `float32`.]

This is how you convert int32 type to float32

```
tf.cast(train_labels, tf.float32)
```

then calculate the loss.

Answer (score 2):

the new version of tensorflow has changed the parameters order of ncs_loss.

try to change as

`tf.nn.nce_loss(nce_weights, nce_biases, train_labels, embed, num_sampled, vocabulary_size)`

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem but with different loss function. You are missing the parameter name, pass parameter with name and error will go away. Check below line of code fro example.

```
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(
                  tf.nn.nce_losss(weights=nce_weights, biases=nce_biases, 
                                  inputs=embed, labels=train_labels, 
                                  num_sampled=num_sampled,
                                  num_classes=vocabulary_size))
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this error, as well. with code very similar to yours.
When I ran it on Floydhub using env=tensorflow (which means Tensorflow 1.1.0 + Keras 2.0.4 on Python3), it threw the above error.

However, it ran fine after i changed the environment to use tensorflow-1.0 (Tensorflow 1.0.0 + Keras 1.2.2 on Python3).